# Flutter&Dart - Problem with starting application

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, encoding

i try everything to add flutter in env also i do the same for dart and still my vs code tell the same error here is the error

Could not find a command named "-".

Usage: dart <command|dart-file> [arguments]

Global options:
-v, --verbose               Show additional command output.
--version               Print the Dart SDK version.
--enable-analytics      Enable analytics.
--disable-analytics     Disable analytics.

Run "dart help " for more information about a command.
See https://dart.dev/tools/dart-tool for detailed documentation.
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 64

i try everything from dart help like fix analyze still the same - this is the error only when i want to start with android emulator (pixel_3a_APi-34_extension_level_7_64) with chrome its okay only i have problem with android ....

Comment: What command are you trying to use? To run the application it should just be 'flutter run' and then it will ask what device you want to run it on. If you are using vscode you can also use the run menu on the top bar. Not sure about android studio or any others

Comment: Yeah mate i run the app and runs without errors but only on Chrome and Edge if i change to android i have this error i dont know what is the solution

Comment: Can you add a screenshot from your terminal trying to run the 'flutter run' command. Is this a new application? Has it ever been run on android? Was is the output of your flutter doctor?